# How to use linkedin mobile sdk to implement third party login?

Tags: android, ios, sdk, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

In order to achieve the linkedin login feature on app-side, 
I want to verify the access-token which passed from app-side to the backend-side

But according to the official documentation, the token getting from sdk cannot be use in their REST api call
(https://stackoverflow.com/a/30082316/4763475)

any idea I can implement the 3rd-party login using linkedin mobile sdk?

Answer (score 0):

According to iOS documentation (which is more explicit):

> *It is important to note that access tokens that are acquired via the Mobile SDK are only usable with the Mobile SDK, and cannot be used to
> make server-side REST API calls.  Similarly, access tokens that you
> already have stored from your users that authenticated using a
> server-side REST API call will not work with the Mobile SDK.*
>
> *Presently, **there is no mechanism available to exchange them**.  If you require tokens that can be used in both the mobile and server-side
> environment, you will need to implement a traditional OAuth 2.0
> solution within your iOS environment to acquire tokens that can be
> leveraged in both situations.*
>
> Source: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/ios-sdk-auth

You may implement something like the solution proposed in this post: [Oauth 2.0 authorization for LinkedIn in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22062145/oauth-2-0-authorization-for-linkedin-in-android)