# Laravel | LinkedIn Login - '401 Unauthorized'

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, linkedin-api

I'm getting another error with my LinkedIn application to be able to login on my website, so I get redirected to the right url, I click on 'Authorize' once I'm on the LinkedIn login page, and I get redirected to a link like this:

> http://localhost:8000/login/linkedin/callback?code=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX...

With the following error:

> Client error: `POST https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response: {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Client authentication failed"}

I don't understand why because I did a Twitter application to login on my website that works with the same controller, and it's perfectly working.. Here is my SocialAuthController:

```
public function redirectToProvider($driver)
    {
        if( ! $this->isProviderAllowed($driver) ) {
            return $this->sendFailedResponse("{$driver} is not currently supported");
        }

        try {
            return Socialite::driver($driver)->redirect();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            // You should show something simple fail message
            return $this->sendFailedResponse($e->getMessage());
        }
    }    

public function handleProviderCallback( $driver )
    {
        try {
            $user = Socialite::driver($driver)->user();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return $this->sendFailedResponse($e->getMessage());
        }

        // check for email in returned user
        return empty( $user->email )
            ? $this->sendFailedResponse("No email id returned from {$driver} provider.")
            : $this->loginOrCreateAccount($user, $driver);
    }
```

My routes:

```
Route::get('login/{driver}', 'Auth\SocialAuthController@redirectToProvider')->name('social.oauth');
Route::get('login/{driver}/callback', 'Auth\SocialAuthController@handleProviderCallback')->name('social.callback');
```

I checked multiple time that all the data between the services.php and the LinkedIn application matchs exactly.. I can't figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
'x-li-src'    => 'msdk'
```

Into `headers` array in file `vendor/laravel/socialite/src/Two/LinkedInProvider.php`

Please check this link for more information [Android LinkedIn SDK produces unusable access tokens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30080583/android-linkedin-sdk-produces-unusable-access-tokens/41221636#41221636)